# Uploading huge dataset

Tags: dataset, bigdata, data, image-classification

I have few questions:

1. Is there a website to upload huge research dataset (over 100GB) for free?
2. Which type of compression (rar, zip ... etc) is good for jpeg images?
3. In case of dataset of 120GB. what is the best split for this big files (eg: 20 GB each)?

Comment: There are several questions on this at the open data stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't compress files that are already compressed (like how JPEG/PNG images or video files are). Their inherent compression is usually good enough, and you only trade some 5% in lower compressed size for a much lengthier and often non-seekable decompression that results in using twice the disk space.

If you need to batch the files together, just use [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29).